# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum not showing thumbnail in lower left corner

Tags: iphone

While the following code is saving the image I took from my application into the camera roll.  I am trying to figure out how to update the thumbnail image that displays in the left corner next to the take image button when you first launch the camera to be the image that I saved.  Shouldn't it always be the last image added to the camera roll?  Here is how I am saving it:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        UIImage *originalImage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(originalImage, nil, nil, nil);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's nothing you can do to change that thumbnail; it's the Camera app's business what goes in there. At any rate, I think it is defined to contain a thumbnail of the last photo you took *using the camera app*.

I just tried this:

1. Launch Camera. Take a photo.
2. Launch Safari. Save an image from a page.
3. Launch Camera. The thumbnail is the photo I took, not the saved image.

I say either let it be or file a bug with Apple if you feel the behavior is incorrect.